# latest android studio 3.2 preview 11 not building

Tags: android, gradle

Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha11-4662957.
Searched in the following locations:

> file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Anandh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app

Comment: that's fine for non-stable builds never expect them to work.

Comment: Google delete jar from server. Click `jar` link for proof https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha11-4662957

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the teams works hard to fix the issues as soon as they come up. If you're using a non-stable version you might get more bugs, but you also get the fixes faster. it's very important for the community to find these bugs early so that they get fixed by the time the stable version is released.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790020/build-errors-after-android-studio-3-2-1-upgrade)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the dependency on GMaven. Make sure you add a dependency on "google()" in your build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google() // here
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
    }
} allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // and here
        jcenter()
}
```