# Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, jcenter

I am building a sample project from Udacity. This was working fine till now, but after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2.1, I am facing the build error below.

Gradle version: 4.6

Project link: https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Sunshine/tree/student/S02.02-Solution-Menus

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971**. Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar Required by:
    project :app
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more details about what version of gradle you are using and which repositories you have in your project by adding the root build.gradle in your question maybe? That would be great.

Comment: @Mohsen I have added the link to the Udacity project.

Comment: The gradle seems pretty old: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`. Have you tried `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` or updating the dependencies? Also, use `implementation` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Did that. Still same error.

Comment: Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290877/7103964 Adding google repo to allprojects fixed my problem.

Comment: Issue is fixed after referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290877/7103964 Thanks @Mohsen

Comment: Well I thought the same so since the gradle version was pretty old. However, I'll add an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

### For Android Studio 3.2.1 update

#### Just add `google()` in root level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()   //  <--here
        jcenter()
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()   //  <-- here
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and see the magic - error is gone.

Comment: thanks, why is there jcenter() in my build.gradle? I add google() and it works.

Comment: I had `jcenter()` and added `google()` afterwards to fix the error.

Comment: @Daniel order doesn't matter too much, generally, but the Google libraries should be listed first since they are more important for building your apps

Comment: Thank you for mentioning where exactly to add "google()"

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Ok, this really fixed it, but can someone explain why?

Comment: may i ask, how in the world did you know about it? IOW,where can i learn such things, too?

Answer (score 8):

The project `gradle` version is pretty old:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

And you are using Android Studio v3.2.1 so, update the `gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' // or 3.2.1 maybe
```

Also, as you can see, it was looking for some packages in :

```
file:/C:/Users/sandeepk2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
```

Which means you probably forgot to add `google()` as the top level repository. Just add `google()`

to your repositories in your root `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 6):

To get this solved

Firstly download the missing Jar file from the link below. I see you are missing version 3.2.1-4818971

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar

Switch your folder structure from Android to Project.

[image: FolderStructure]

Now navigate to the libs folder inside the app - build folder. (If the libs folder does not exist, you can create it by right clicking on the app folder - select New - select Directory.)

[image: LibsFolder]

Paste the downloaded.jar file inside libs folder. Right click on the jar file and at the bottom click on Add as library. This will take care of adding implementation files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle [You don't have to manually enter this in your build file].

[image: AddAsLibrary]

Everything should be okay once you sync after doing the above.
Here is the source link to this solution: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#download_aapt2

Let me know if you run into any other issues whilst doing the above.

Comment: Why Google is not bundling this in their repo? Android dev exp is the worst I had

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, as d4rkcon said download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
But you can do simplier - just put this file in directory where Andoid Studio is trying to find it. If you don't have directories like /tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/ in AndroidSDK folder just create them and then put aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar file in.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I had to add 3 levels of directories.   Also there are 3 flavors of the jar file.  On a mac it is: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar
(substitute osx or linux for windows in the jar file)

Answer (score 3):

Add Google repository in your build.gradle(Project:xxxxx)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

clear gradle cache

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

and resync to download all dependencies

Comment: yes, this is the solution, after upgrading gradle, must resync all dependencies for run this command successfully: react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

Change your build.gradle as follows.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name here"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add google() on your build script > repositories
add google on allprojects > repositories

use implementation as replacement of compile keyword,
also on your filetree.

EX.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.6.3 update : just adding google maven tag in buildscript and all projects repositories in build.gradle file of project file solves the issue.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with additional information? What differs in this configuration from other, previous answers? Do the previous approaches not work in Android Studio 3.6.3? What specific parts of your configuration are key to the solution? Is it primarily the `maven {}` configurations?

Comment: yes , other answers do not solve issues on the latest android studio update.