# How to fix "Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueReporter'." error on Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I use IntelliJ IDEA for creating #Flutter projects and I have the Android Studio for installation purposes of Flutter onto my machine. The problem arose when I upgraded the Android Studio from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1. Moreover, after this upgrade, I'm no longer able to create any project in both IDEs.

The error message in IntelliJ

[image]

The error message in Android Studio

[image]

*P.S. Those are the default programs of both IDEs namely, IntelliJ and Android Studio.*

any newly-created project brings up this error; however, previously-created projects work perfectly fine.

My machine has 64-bit OS, x64-based Processor

IntelliJ

```
 IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 (Community Edition)

 Build #IC-183.5153.38, built on January 9, 2019

 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 amd64

 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

 Windows 10 10.0
```

Android Studio

```
 Android Studio 3.2.1

 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018

 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64

 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

 Windows 10 10.0
```

project's build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they                 
            belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

the individual module build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nonna.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner                 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-        
core:3.0.2'
}
```

I have checked those questions but unfortunately, the error wasn't fixed.

[Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790020/build-errors-after-android-studio-3-2-1-upgrade)

[Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0/50290877#50290877)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue got solved and now the IDE is working like a charm. 
As it was seen from the provided screenshots there was an error in the Android Gradle plugin, so to solve this issue follow the numbered steps in the newly provided screenshots below.

[(Part 1) Solving gradle issue due to upgrading Android Studio to 3.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80h3h.png)

- Step 0: From the left panel in your IDE, choose the **android
  [name_of_project]** folder
- Step 1: look for the **build.gradle** file then double click it to
  start editing it
- Step 2: change exactly the line that states 
  **`classpath
  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`** to the current version of
  your Android Studio, in other terms, **`classpath
  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`** in my case.

[(Part 2) Solving gradle issue due to upgrading Android Studio to 3.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dn0w.png)

- Step 3: After finishing from Steps 1 & 2, go to the **gradle** folder
- Step 4: Double click on the **wrapper** subfolder
- Step 5: Click the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file to start editing
  it
- Step 6: make sure that your gradle version is compatible with your
  current Android Studio
  **`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`**

**The Android Gradle plugin 3.3.0 requires the Gradle version of 4.10.1 and newer.**

***Disclaimer:*** *you need to do these steps whenever you create a new project on whatever IDE you use namely, Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA, and VS Code.*