# Android Studio IDE emulator opens, but project is not running/Compling

Tags: android, android-studio

When I compiled my Android Studio IDE project, the emulator had opened, but  project didn't run.I am using the latest version of Android IDE and I uninstalled Android IDE couple of times, and then again reinstalled it. Still, the problem persists.

Please help me fixing this problem.

When I run my Android Studio IDE project, I got this message at Build window:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.1-5013011.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/zunayeed/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0)

Comment: @GinoMempin's link provides a valid answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790020/build-errors-after-android-studio-3-2-1-upgrade)

Answer (score 14):

I think you missed google repository on your gradle file. To use AAPT2, make sure that you have a google() dependency in your build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    google() // here
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha12'

  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
  google() // and here
  jcenter()
 }
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? I am new to this area. Where can I find build.gradle file ? I am still kind of confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just had upgraded gradle build of your some old project, then you might try the following in your build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
google()
jcenter()
}
```

Comment: I didn't upgrade. How can I upgrade the gradle of my android IDE ?

Comment: If you have latest android studio, then it will ask you to upgrade gradle build through a pop-up, Further you can go through this post https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin